# changing page title on back button with jQuery Address

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

Utilizing jQuery Address to enable the browser's back button, I was able to leverage the plugin's event "onExternalChange" to detect when the browser actually hits the back button, so that I could trigger the page title to change on that as well. Unfortunately I can't get it to grab the current section, as it grabs it before it jumps, thus being one off everytime:

```
$.address.externalChange(function() {
    var lastPageTitle = 'Kevin Dare Foundation | ' + $('nav').find('.active').html();
    $.address.title(lastPageTitle);
});
```

link: http://nickdimatteo.com/kjd

Comment: So let me get this straight; if the user clicks the back button you want to change the title of the page being loaded (previous page)?

Comment: Yep! The code I pasted does that, it grabs the html from the active nav link to generate the title text, but (I believe) it's grabbing the active state before it switches to the new section, thus grabbing the wrong "active" section.

Comment: I think I found a solution: http://snippi.com/s/wa9tgi3

Comment: post the solution in case someone else wanders in here looking for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the following solves the problem:

```
//Change Page Title on browser back button press
$.address.externalChange(function() {
    var hash = document.location.hash.replace(/^#\//, '');
    var lastPageTitle = 'Kevin Dare Foundation | ' + $('nav a[href="#'+hash+'"]').html();
    if(hash) {
    $.address.title(lastPageTitle);
    }
    else //account for no hash
  {
  $.address.title('Kevin Dare Foundation');
  }
});
```